# react js popover overlay not working. Getting 'React.createElement type is invalid expected a string

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to get a react-bootstrap working for popover and overlaytrigger working. I have multiple buttons and like to call a function to get popover formatting for each button. I am getting the following error

"React.createElement: type is invalid -- expect a string"

I look at the react example over and over again, still stuck on this error
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#popover-examples

here is my code so far

```
render() {
  return (

  <OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="top" 
    overlay={this.Overlay()}>
    <Button>Test</Button>
  </OverlayTrigger>
  );
}

Overlay = () => {
  const popover = (
    <Popover id="1">
      <Popover.Title as-"h3">Title One</Popover.Title>
      <Popover.Content>Test Content
      </Popover.Content>
    </Popover>
  );
  return popover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `this.Overlay()` is incorrect becasue:

1. You are already calling the function, something like `() => this.Overlay()` or `Overlay.bind(this)` will make sense.
2. `this` has no property `Overlay` on it since it's defined outside.

Regarding the issue, your code seems fine, just a small typo `as-"h3"` should be `as="h3"` and make `Overlay` a `const` or optionally a `function`.

Example:

```js
const Overlay = () => {
  const popover = (
    <Popover id="1">
      <Popover.Title as="h3">Title One</Popover.Title>
      <Popover.Content>Test Content</Popover.Content>
    </Popover>
  );
  return popover;
};

class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="top" overlay={Overlay}>
        <Button>Test</Button>
      </OverlayTrigger>
    );
  }
}
```

You can check it out in sandbox her: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-proskuriakova-jgkre

Answer (score 0):

If Overlay is s functional component, you should use the tag instead of calling the function on `OverlayTrigger`. React will call the function when rendering the component.

Try

`overlay={<Overlay/>}`

Answer (score 0):

That should work if you call a const instead of the function. I've managed to avoid the error but when the button is clicked, the popover is not being shown.

this is placed at the top of my React Component

```
<OverlayTrigger
  trigger="click"
  placement="top"
  overlay={PopoverCustomer}>
  <Button variant="secondary">OK</Button>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

and then I declare this const

```
const PopoverCustomer = () => (
<Popover>
  <Popover.Title>
    Title
  </Popover.Title>
  <Popover.Content>
    Some content here
  </Popover.Content>
</Popover>
);
```